# Using regular expression in Nightwatchjs

Tags: javascript, regex, xpath, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to find any attribute that matches a certain pattern. Since i can't find any information about which xPath version NightwatchJS is using, i tried it with matches, but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm searching for certain date patterns like
19 May 2017 or
19.05.2017 or
19-05-2017

My current regular expression is

```
/\b[0-9]{1,2}.([a-zA-Z]{3,}|[0-9]{1,2}).[0-9]{4}\b/g
```

or hard coded

```
/\b[19]{1,2}.([May]{3,}|[05]{1,2}).[2017]{4}\b/g
```

and the full nightwtach expression would be

```
client.useXpath().click("//*[matches(@*, '/\b[19]{1,2}.([May]{3,}|[05]{1,2}).[2017]{4}\b/g')]");
```

So is just my expression wrong or doesn't nightwatch use xpath 2.0?

Comment: I'm not sure what `matches` is supposed to return here, but the *initial* regex is fine. https://regex101.com/r/WlM1DG/1/.  The others don't really make sense,  because you're using character classes around what you're asserting is a static string:  `[2017]` would match 0000,0001,0002...7777 (about 4^4 or 256 different permutations!)

Comment: @sweaver2112
okay thank you. Do you know how would solve that problem so it would only match the date or would it be to long like `[2]{1}[0]{1}[1]{1}[7]{1}` as example for the year or is this the only correct option?

`matches` should just link me to the containing html-element and perform a click operation on it

Comment: it's easier than that, your hard-coded "may 19th" pattern would be: `\b19.(May|05).2017\b`